# vim-r tmux scrolling not working properly

Tags: r, vim, scroll, tmux, vim-r

A few months ago I set up the combination of `Vim-R-plugin+tmux` on my macbook air as well as scrolling (using `MouseTerm` inside `SIMBL`). All this works perfectly fine; In particular, the scrolling works well both in the vim editor and in the adjacent R session.

I am now trying to get the same setup on my macbook pro, but the scrolling seems to work only partially:

- It woks in the vim editor, but not inside the R session.
- The only 'scrolling' that works inside the R session is by typing `leader+[` followed by the up arrow key which is all very tedious as the cursor goes up one row at the time (note: scrolling with the mouse doesn't work at all)

I am using the same .Rprofile, .vimrc and .tmux.comf on both machines. I am puzzled as to where the difference is coming from.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Is one on tmux 2.1 or later, and the other a version older than 2.1? In 2.1 some mouse-mode differences were introduced. https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/145

Comment: That's certainly one difference, well spotted! 
I'm trying to install tmux version 2.0 on the macbook pro, but 'brew install tmux 2.0' doesn't work and I can't find manual installation instructions for this particular version. Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: For future reference: I solved the issue by installing an tmux 2.0 from a tarball as explained in https://github.com/ThomasAdam/tmux. It was indeed the tmux version that most likely caused this issue

Comment: You already took care of this but FYI you can try various things to install older versions of homebrew formulae, as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/2449905